# jQuery Mobile stop taphold propagation to parent

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm building a page where I want to utilize taphold to launch a contextMenu. However, when an element is inside a parent the taphold propagates to this parent. I want to prevent this.

so when a user holds the child, ONLY the child taphold function should launch, and when the user holds the parent ONLY the parent should launch.

I tried el.stopPropagation() and el.stopImmediatePropagation(), but both didn't stop the taphold from propagating to the parent.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mtvnksL/) will show the problem. Holding the green child also triggers the taphold of the red parent

The fiddle shows two divs:

```
<div class='parent'>
   <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

and uses this code:

```
$('.parent').on('taphold', function( el ){
   alert( 'parent' );
});

$('.child').on('taphold', function( el ){
   alert( 'child' );
});
```

if you tap and hold the green div the red will also trigger, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `taphold` is not so easy as other events, because to recognize it, there is the need to start a `timer` which should check the *elapsed time* from the initial screen pressure (JQM is using its own `vmousedown` event). So, after the `tapholdThreshold` has been elapsed - usually 750 ms - the framework can raise the `taphold` event.

I believe to get the *perfect* solution You may need to patch JQM, otherwise here is a quick workaround:

```
$('.parent').on('taphold', function( e ) {
    if(e.target == e.currentTarget) {
        // do the action
    }
});
```

The `taphold` will be raised anyway, but You can trap the origin and skip the execution of Your code.

Comment: This looked very promising and worked like a charm emulating a mobile device on Google Chrome for instance, but when I try this on an actual mobile device the default 'right click' (where you can open in new tab, read later, etc) pops up in Chrome. Is there a way to disable that default browser contextMenu?

Comment: Mobile device OS-Versions hell... As for the right-click You can use `oncontextmenu="return false;"`- but for the default device `taphold`I believe You may try this: [touch-callout equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013156/4845566) . Let me know...